# What kinds of variables will be stored in Text?

Tags: c++, memory, text

I know that global variables (memory)  will be stored in Data but what kinds of variable will be stored in Text (Memory location)?

Comment: What do you mean by "text"?

Comment: Are you talking about segments of the binary layout i.e. [.text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) and [.data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)?

Comment: No, I was talking about the memory location, likes heap, stack. For the .text, I am not sure because professor didn't mention that.

Comment: Heap or stack depends on how you write the code. If you allocate memory (using new) it will be on the heap. For [automatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) variables they will be on the stack.

Comment: @HuangMolly There you go: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

Comment: @PaulRooney Like int *array = new int [3]{1,2 ,3}?

Comment: @Everyone Thank you !

Comment: @HuangMolly yes that an allocation on the heap, unless you `delete[]` it that memory is leaked. For stack use `int array2[3] = {1,2,3};`, which requires no delete but that stack space will be reused after the current scope (basically after '}') ends.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: No variables go in the .text section. It's either the heap, stack or data.

Comment: In many executable formats, the *text* section is a read-only section where the code is placed.  Since it is read-only, only compile-time constants are placed into the *text* section.  Variables are not constants, so they are not placed into the *text* section.  Although this policy may be changed by supplying instructions to the linkers. YMMV.